# Rails has_many :through and has_one :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through, has-one

First I'm using **Rails 3.1** from the **3-1-stable** branch updated an hour ago.

I'm developing an application where I have 3 essential models **User**, **Company** and **Job**, Here's the relevant part of the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies_users, class_name: "CompaniesUsers"
  has_many :companies, :through => :companies_users, :source => :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies_users, class_name: "CompaniesUsers"
  has_many :employees, :through => :companies_users, :source => :user
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :counter_cache => true
end

class CompaniesUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The code works just fine, but I have been wondering if it's possible to:

I want to link a **job** with an **employer**, so think of this scenario: A user **John** who's an employee at **Example**, he posted the job Rails Developer, so I want to access **@job.employer** and it should get me back the user **John**, in other words:

```
@user = User.find_by_name('john')
@job   = Job.find(1)
@job.employer == @user       #=> true
```

So I thought of two possible solutions

## First solution

```
class Job
  has_one :employer, :through => :employers
end

class User
  has_many :jobs, :through => :employers
end

class Employer
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## Second solution

```
class Job
  has_one :employer, :class_name => "User"
end

class User
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Which route should I go? Is my code right ?

I have another question, how to get rid of the class_name => "CompaniesUsers" option passed to has_many, should the class be Singular or Plural ? Should I rename it to something like **Employees** ?

P.S: I posted the same question to [Ruby on Rails: Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/eaed1874d65ed7dc)

Comment: Do you want one Job to belong to just one Employer (User)?

Comment: Yes, a Job should belongs to only one employer (User) and a user has many Jobs. However the User that owns the job must be an employee at the company the job posted at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I'd suggest simply doing

```
class Job
  belongs_to :employer, :class_name => "User"
end

class User
  has_many :jobs
end
```

This would give you methods like

```
user = User.first
user.jobs.create(params)
user.jobs # array
job = user.jobs.first
job.employer == user # true
```

You'll need an `employer_id` integer field in your Jobs table for this to work.

Comment: The problem is a job already belongs to a company (see my code above) so I should make it polymorphic association right ? Although I have the :counter_cache enabled on the association from Job to Company how can I enable this through Polymorphic association ?

Comment: Job belonging to a company shouldn't be a problem. That would be stored in `company_id`.

Comment: Your Company has many users, and User has many companies, but the Job should just belong to _one_ company and _one_ user, right?

Comment: Exactly, a job belongs to one company and one user, but not just any user, a user that is an employee of this company.. in other words company.employee.include?(user) #=> true

Comment: But since a User can have many companies, you'll have to store both Company and User in the Job model. You'll probably need some validation to ensure that the User does have that Company.

Comment: So I should implement it as a belongs_to/has_many as described above but add some validation that the user belongs to the company before saving the job ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only way in this case to me. Can you think of some better alternative?

Comment: I don't either.. Thanks I'll work on it, If I ever has a problem or I have a better idea I'll reopen the question.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to name your pass through model:

```
company_user
```

Then you don't need this:

```
class_name: "CompaniesUsers"
```

Just make sure the name of your database table is:

```
company_users
```

What you have works for you, so that's great.  I just find when I don't follow convention I 
run in to trouble down the road.